# How much more likely are NIH administrative supplements to be funded than new proposals?

Tags: funding, nih

The U.S. National Institutes of Health (NIH) offers [administrative supplements](https://grants.nih.gov/grants/administrative-supplements.htm) that provide additional funding to existing awards, for example to meet specific NIH priority areas.

I am guessing that these are much more likely to be funded than comparable projects submitted as their own, for example, R21s (whose budgets and timelines are comparable to certain administrative supplements). Is this correct? Are there any statistics available about funding rates for supplements?

Comment: I can't imagine there would be data on this.  Have you talked to your Program Officer about this mechanism?  It's not going to be used just to fund inflation, e.g.  I would want to make sure I checked with a PO prior to submitting to make sure the ask is in line with the point of the supplement.